# iText html2pdf Issue with visualization of label in PDF after conversion from HTML

Tags: java, html, css, itext, pdf-generation

I use:

- html2pdf v2.0.1
- iText 7.1.1

In my HTML I have following label that takes the entire width of the page:

```
<label class="test">Patient</label>
```

This is my css:

```
.test {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #009fd1;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background: #085a9f;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[image: Label visualisation in HTML]

When I convert the HTML to PDF using iText, my label is however displayed like this:

[image: Label visualisation in HTML]

It looks to me like he took everything correct, except for the `display: block` and the `border-radius: 3px`

Is this a problem in iText?

To be complete, here is my conversion code:

```
    public ByteArrayOutputStream createPdf(String html) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    html = replaceStylesheet(html);
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        //Add metadata
        writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baos, writerProperties);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
        //Set the document to be tagged
        pdfDoc.setTagged();
        PdfViewerPreferences pdfViewerPreferences = new PdfViewerPreferences();
        pdfViewerPreferences.setDisplayDocTitle(true);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(pdfViewerPreferences);

        //Create event-handlers
        String header = "© 2018 Generated by OpenNCP Portal";
        Header headerHandler = new Header(header);
        PageXofY footerHandler = new PageXofY(pdfDoc);

        //Assign event-handlers
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE,headerHandler);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE,footerHandler);

        // pdf conversion
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider dfp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false);

        props.setFontProvider(dfp);

        HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(html, pdfDoc, props);
        footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDoc);
        pdfDoc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred when converting HTML to PDF", e);
    }
    return baos;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it's the problem in current version of iText and you are right in your assumptions.

There are two distinct issues, the first one is that in pdfHTML `display:block` for `label` element is not supported, instead it defaults to `inline`.
However it seems that for `label` it's fairly easy to support `display:block`, you simply need to extend the `DefaultTagWorkerFactory` and `DefaultCssApplierFactory` like this:

```
private static class LabelBlockTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (!TagConstants.LABEL.equals(tag.name())) {
            return null;
        }
        String display;
        if (tag.getStyles() == null || (display = tag.getStyles().get(CssConstants.DISPLAY)) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (CssConstants.BLOCK.equals(display)) {
            return new DivTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private static class LabelBlockCssApplierFactory extends DefaultCssApplierFactory {
    @Override
    public ICssApplier getCustomCssApplier(IElementNode tag) {
        if (!TagConstants.LABEL.equals(tag.name())) {
            return null;
        }
        String display;
        if (tag.getStyles() == null || (display = tag.getStyles().get(CssConstants.DISPLAY)) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (CssConstants.BLOCK.equals(display)) {
            return new BlockCssApplier();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you can set them in `ConverterProperties`:

```
props.setTagWorkerFactory(new LabelBlockTagWorkerFactory());
props.setCssApplierFactory(new LabelBlockCssApplierFactory());
```

The second issue is with the `border-radius` property support for background of inline elements. It's actually currently a bug in iText and it's not entirely trivial to fix, however it works fine for block elements, so it should not be the issue for you right now, after you solve the `display:block` problem.